# Playframework Scala Authentication Builder Cached onUnauthorized

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I'm trying to cached the Unauthorized result from the auth builder, but i can't find a way to properly request the result from cache (without using redirect with reverse route) any idea? this is my code:

```
  object Authenticated extends AuthenticatedBuilder(
    request =>
      request.session.get("email"),
    request =>
        Unauthorized(html.index("fail!", loginForm))
   )
```

I want to do something like:

```
  object Authenticated extends AuthenticatedBuilder(
    request =>
      request.session.get("email"),
    request =>
      Cached("Fail") { Action { implicit request =>
        Unauthorized(html.index("fail!", loginForm))
        }
      }
   )
```

this will of course return Cached instead of simpleResult and fail...

btw i'm using play 2.2.1

Comment: Have you tried using [Play's cache](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.1/ScalaCache)? The `getOrElse` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Peter i was able to return a `SimpleResult` with `getOrElse`, my final code is a bit more complex but here is an example that hopefully will help more people:

```
  import play.api.cache.Cache
  import play.api.Play.current
  import play.api.mvc.Security.AuthenticatedBuilder

  object Authenticated extends AuthenticatedBuilder(
    request =>
      request.session.get("email"),
    request =>
      Cache.getOrElse("UnAuth"){
        Unauthorized("Fail")
      }
   )
```